# Parsing formdata with php

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax, form-submit

I have this `AJAX` `POST` request coming from `AngularJS`, an `JSON` model with some fields and a file:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarywlEiXuTa9EkwFUWz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="model"

{"fname":"and","lname":"and","email":"asd@asd.com","phone":"+3912345","position":"Marketing","startdate":"10/10/2017"}

------WebKitFormBoundarywlEiXuTa9EkwFUWz

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="InterviewPreparation.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

------WebKitFormBoundarywlEiXuTa9EkwFUWz--
```

I'm a php dummy developer. How can I parse the request using PHP? This code doesn't work:

```
<?php
// mail.php

$errors = array();  // array to hold validation errors
$data = array();        // array to pass back data

// validate the variables ========
if (empty($_POST['model.fname']))
  $errors['First name'] = 'Required.';
if (empty($_POST['model.lname']))
  $errors['Last Name'] = 'Required.';
if (empty($_POST['model.email']))
  $errors['Email'] = 'Required.';
if (empty($_POST['model.phone']))
  $errors['Phone'] = 'Required.';
if (empty($_POST['model.position']))
  $errors['Position'] = 'Required.';
if (empty($_POST['model.startdate']))
  $errors['Start Date'] = 'Required.';

// return a response ==============
$file = $_POST['file'];
if (! empty($file))
  echo 'Uploaded file: ' + $file.name;

// response if there are errors
if (! empty($errors)) {
  // if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
  $data['success'] = false;
  $data['errors']  = $errors;
} else {
  // if there are no errors, return a message
  $data['success'] = true;
  $data['message'] = 'Mail sent, good luck!';
}
// return all our data to an AJAX call
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: Content-type: multipart/formdata with 2 attributes: 'model' is a JSON and 'file' is a FILE

Answer (score 0):

The name of your first form-data field is "model", it contains a JSON object that is treated like a string in PHP unless you json_decode it first.

So I would suggest doing something like the following:

```
$model = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'model'); // better to not use $_POST directly
$decoded = json_decode($model);
if(!$decoded)
    // not valid json
if(empty($decoded->fname))
    $errors['First name'] = 'Required.';
// etc...
```

The file should be in $_FILES array.

```
$file = $_FILES['file'];
```

Comment: Thanks Brense, I'm struggling with this code. In your code if I echo $model I get null. It means I can't get the parameter 'model' from the request. How should I read this POST raw data back in PHP? As a stream or what? It's a post with Content-type 'multipart/formdata'.

Comment: $stream = fopen('php://input', 'rb');
$string = stream_get_contents($stream);

var_dump($string); //This dump gives me string(0) ""

Comment: whats the result if you do `var_dump($_POST);`? form-data shouldnt be in the input stream. PHP automagically adds the form-data fields to the $_POST array.